# ActionScript: fscommand vs ExternalInterface

Tags: flash, actionscript, externalinterface, fscommand

In ActionScript you have two options to communicate to the host. (In my case a .NET app that uses  AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll to host the flash movie)

```
fscommand(String, ...);

ExternalInterface.call(String, ...);
```

what are the main differences between the two?

Could it be that fscommand arrives with a little delay on the host side? (i.e. it is not blocking and could therefore get mixed up with ExternalInterface calls?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExternalInterface` is a direct replacement for `fscommand`, which was the old method (pre Flash player 8) of communicating between Flash and the container application (see [Adobe documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cab.html)).

From the documentation again, the advantages of `ExternalInterface` over `fscommand` are as follows:

- You can use any JavaScript function, not only the functions that you
  can use with the fscommand() function.
- You can pass any number of arguments, with any names; you aren't
  limited to passing a command and a single string argument. This gives
  the external API much more flexibility than fscommand().
- You can pass various data types (such as Boolean, Number, and
  String); you are no longer limited to String parameters.
- You can receive the value of a call, and that value returns
  immediately to ActionScript (as the return value of the call you make).

If you're targeting Flash Player 8 or later the recommendation is that you use `ExternalInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I would recommend using ExternalInterface over fscommand. I regard fscommand more or less as deprecated.

That said, what you mention about fscommand being non-blocking could be correct, since ExternalInterface.call() is synchronous, to be able to return a value from the called external function. I guess there could be situations, edge cases, where that could speak in favor of fscommand, but you would probably have to test that.

Again, I would recommend ExternalInterface, it has many features fscommand doesn't have, like preserving data types and automatic serialization/deserialization of objects between ActionScript and the typical external environment - JavaScript in a web page - whereas fscommand only sends strings. Using ExternalInterface in a .NET app, you may have to parse the XML-RPC (that is used internally by ExternalInterface) your self, I believe, but I'm not sure.